# Django using custom signals to send mail

Tags: django, django-views, django-signals

In my sample, signal function was created in  models.py.Instead of this,i think it is possible to do using custom signals concept.

my models.py for signals function is

```
class Book(models.Model):
    [..........]

def send_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.author_name:
        message = "Book is updated"
        subject = "Updates"
        send_mail(subject, message, your_email,
            [instance.email,])

post_save.connect(send_update, sender=Book)
```

views.py is

```
if request.POST:
        form = BookForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            form.save()
            return redirect('/index/')
    return render_to_response('addbook.html',{ 'form':form },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Instead of this how can we create a custom signals using signals.py file to send the mail.

I am trying to learn this in practical,an example will help me to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to define your own signal, instead of using `pre_save`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from app.models import Book

def send_update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.author_name:
        message = "Book is updated"
        subject = "Updates"
        send_mail(subject, message, your_email,
            [instance.email,])

post_save.connect(send_update, sender=Book)
```

Register the signals by importing it in the app's `__init__.py` file. This will allow to `import models` from `signals.py`.

`__init__.py`

```
import signals
```

Comment: import signal give no module named signals how ?

Answer (score 1):

Define your signal and receiver in `signals.py`:

```
from django.dispatch import Signal

post_update = Signal(providing_args = ['instance'])

def send_update(...):
    ....

post_update.connect(send_update, sender = Book)
```

In `views.py`, send the signal right after you save the form:

```
instance = form.save()
post_update.send(sender = Book, instance = instance)
```

Comment: Instead of using models.py for defining and connecting signal can we use separate signals.py file for doing that.If so please guide me how to do

Comment: You can put that code in `signals.py`, and it'll work. However, I recommend `connect`ing the signal inside your `models.py`, because receives should be defined and connected in the same file.

Comment: where should i define the send_update method which i already mentioned in models.py

Comment: I tend to keep receivers in my `models.py`, because those files are always loaded by Django and then I'm sure the signals will get connected. If they get too big, I keep the receiver in models, but delegate the work to functions I define in `controllers.py`, which is where you should store logic that isn't strictly model-related.

Comment: my thought was don't to disturb the models.py,instead of that i have to keep this send_update function in views.py or listeners.py,i am not much familiar with signals so please help me sir

Comment: There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to keep the listeners in their own file, as long as you're sure that by the time your code executes a send on a signal, all the listeners are registered. The cleanest way without putting receiver code in `models.py` would then be to put them in `signals.py`. That will guarantee that all the receivers will be connected before you do any sends, because to send any of the signals, you'll first import the file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26696/discussion-between-user2086641-and-valtron)

Comment: Put it in `signals.py`, then.